# How to save a existing project as a project template in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, express, webstorm

I am using WebStorm 8 and I want to save my existing Express.js project as a project template. How to do that in WebStorm ?

Answer (score 3):

there is no such feature in WebStorm. Please vote for [WEB-11807](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11807) to be notified on any update

Comment: That ticket is marked as fixed, but I still don't see the feature in WebStorm.  Do you know what the status is?

Comment: it's fixed in the next major release (2019) that is not yet available for downloading. It's currently in alpha, first EAP builds will be published in January